# Vim: create marks across files?

Tags: vim

A feature I often use in Vim is `m`ark and jump-to-mark (`'`)… But they only work within a file.

Is there any way to create a mark which works across files? For example, so I can create mark `a` on line 42 of `foo.py`, then jump to that mark while I'm editing `bar.py`?

Comment: a (semi)-polite suggestion to those who wish to close vim questions - just add them to your ignore list!

Comment: Thanks Peter. It would be nice to see what the reason for the close-vote was…

Comment: it was 'belongs on superuser.com'

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Yes. Use capital letters for the mark.

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_marks

Marks can span across files. To use such marks one has to use upper-case registers i.e. A-Z. Lower-case registers are used only within files and do not span files. That's to say, if you were to set a mark in a file foo.c in register "a" and then move to another file and hit 'a, the cursor will not jump back to the previous location. If you want a mark which will take you to a different file then you will need to use an upper-case register. For example, use mA instead of ma.

Comment: oh the keystrokes i would have saved had i known of this years ago!

Comment: I swear, it's like every time I come up with this weird thing I want to do, I always have that thought "hm, I wonder if vim does this..." and sure enough

Answer (score 13):

Use the `A-Z` marks, they are available across files.

Comment: Thanks :) I hope you aren't offended if I give the answer to nall… He seems to need the rep a *little* more ;)

Comment: marks and registers are different, register A is not the same as mark A... in fact, there is no register 'A', yanking to register A will append the yanked text to register 'a' instead.